# Is the envelope now defunct?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Now that we have that "all SX site" notification thingy in the top left (no, the other top left), the envelope seems a bit redundant.  In particular, since clicking on one doesn't clear the other, it's annoyingly redundant.  I can see that for those power users who regularly use all the SX sites then it's useful to have a way of knowing if the notifications pertain to the particular site that they're on at that moment, but for a mere mortal like myself, the two have enough overlap that it seems silly to have both.  I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to have the "all SX site" refine its display to distinguish between the current site and other sites as well, which would make the envelope completely redundant.

So, can it go?  Or at the very least, can the two sync themselves?

Comment: The global inbox doesn't show changes to favorites.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the envelope notification is somewhat redundant. Yet the envelope informs me of reputation changes, favorites, and badges earned. These, to my knowledge, are not included in the "all SE sites" inbox. I do not know about revisions.

I do agree that it is annoying when the envelope notification fires long after I visited the comment or answer through the SE inbox. Sync would be the better solution: let it only fire if the SE inbox has not been visited for all changes and vice versa.

Comment: Right, so there's stuff in the envelope that I don't know about!  ('fraid I grew up on an SE1.0 site so don't know all about the fancy Swiss-Army-Envelope that is on the other sites).  Still, as you say, syncing would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It is now, yes:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/